# Error Message: "Authorization_RequestDenied","Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am creating a console c# app and using below code to access my email object. This is my first application. I am able to generate Token but after that I am getting insufficient permission error.

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"aa24be4b-9d63-4460-83ef-9095d21fb483","date":"2019-06-16T10:07:06"}}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string _clientId = "hiddenforprivacy";
        public const string _aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";        
        public const string _tenantId = "hiddenforprivacy";
        public const string _resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
        public const string _appKey = "hiddenforprivacy";
        static string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _aadInstance, _tenantId);

        private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private static AuthenticationContext _context = null;
        private static ClientCredential _credential = null;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            _credential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _appKey);
            Task<string> _token = GetToken();
            _token.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(_token.Result);

            Task<string> _users = GetUsers(_token.Result);
            _users.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(_users.Result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetUsers(string result)
        {
            string _users1 = null;
            string _queryString = "api-version=1.6";
            var _uri = "https://graph.windows.net/TENANT-ID/users?" + _queryString;

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
            var _getResult = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_uri);
            if (_getResult != null)
            {
                _users1 = await _getResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return _users1;
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            AuthenticationResult _result = null;
            string _token2 = null;
            _result = await _context.AcquireTokenAsync(_resource, _credential);
            _token2 = _result.AccessToken;
            return _token2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have granted API Permission to 
User.Read.All, 
Mail.Read, Directory.Read.All,
Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Comment: None Tony. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a possibility to convert this into Dot.Net Framework 2,3, 3.5. As my server does not support framework 4 and 4.5

Comment: Sorry, I know little about .net, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using client credentials flow, so you need to grant **application type** permission. It seems that you granted delegated permissions, you need to grant application permissions.

[image]

By the way, we strongly recommend that you use [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) instead of [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) to access Azure Active Directory resources.